# Redirect page but still bring data on Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i want to redirect page from controller, but still bring data / data still there (data name is "valueOne")

i tried with this code

```
return redirect()->back()->with('alert','test');
```

or

```
return view('login');
```

this is my form in blade :

```
//this data i get from other page, and keep this on this blade
<input id="valueOne" name="valueOne" type="hidden" value="{{ $result->valueOne }}">


    <form action="{{URL::to('/getHalaman')}}" method="post" id="form1">
    <div class="numberOne">Number One : 
      <select id="numberOne" name="numberOne">
        <option value="null" id="numberOne">-- choose --</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="numberTwo" style="text-align: center;">Number Two : 
      <select id="numberTwo" name="numberTwo" style="width: 200px;">
        <option value="null">-- choose --</option>
        <option value="aa">aa</option>
        <option value="bb">bb</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <br>
      <div class="button" style="text-align: center;">
      <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $result->id }}">
      <script src="js/testButton.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <button id="buttonSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"> Konfirmasi </button>
    </div>
      {{ csrf_field() }}
     </div>
     </form>
```

this is my controller :

```
function getHalaman(Request $req){
    $req->numberTwo == 'null';

        return redirect()->back()->with('alert','error');
    try {
         if($req->numberTwo == 'aa'){
            return view('numberOne')->with('a',$req->numberOne)->with('jaminan',$req->numberTwo)->with('id',$req->id);  
        } else {
            return view('numberTwo')->with('a',$req->numberOne)->with('jaminan',$req->numberTwo)->with('id',$req->id);
        }

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return view('login');
    }
}
```

this is my route :

```
Route::post('/getHalaman', 'userController@getHalaman');
```

i try and i get error like valueOne not found

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

my expected is, if user not choose that option numberTwo, will redirect on that page but still bring valueOne

anyone can help me ? very thanks is want to help me ..

Comment: `return redirect()->back()->with('alert','test');` its store in the flash Session , for get this you need to do like `Session::get('alert');`

Comment: @KaranSadana where i must put that ? sorry i am new in laravel

Comment: @KaranSadana can you give me example sir ?

Comment: see in my answer

Comment: from where $result is coming? is it stored in session? @YeruAdi

Comment: @MaulikShah stored in session ? i dont know.. but i make this not stored in session.. sorry sir, i new here.. can you explain me ? or give me example ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you sending data using `with` its store in flash Session data, which means you need to get this data from the session. see laravel documentation about this. [Flash Data to view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

so for getting data from the session in view is like below

```
@if(Session::has('alert'))
<div class="alert">{{ Session::get('alert')}}</div>
@endif
```

First, we checking session has alert or not, in case you not send

Comment: check the name you passing with name , hence i use `alert` , `return redirect()->back()->with('alert','test');` so m using alert to get

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="numberTwo" style="text-align: center;">Number Two : 
  <select id="numberTwo" name="numberTwo" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="null">-- choose --</option>
    @foreach ($titles as $key => $val)
    @if(Session::has('alert'))
          <option value="{{ Session::get('alert')}}" selected>{{ Session::get('alert')}}</option>
    @else
          <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $val }}</option>
    @endif      
    @endforeach
  </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have another option to return input with
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('alert','test');

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

First comopser dump-autoload

```
composer dump-autoload
```

In your view,

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
     <p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif
```

Hope this helps :)